# How to for-loop three columns per row in Django/python?

Tags: python, django, for-loop

I would like to display data, three columns per row during my for. I would like my result to look like the following:

```
<table>
<tr><td>VALUE1</td><td>VALUE2</td><td>VALUE3</td></tr>
<tr><td>VALUE4</td><<td>VALUE5</td><td>VALUE6</td></tr>
</table>
```

Anyone know how to do it?

Syntax Error
TemplateSyntaxError at /

'for' statements should use the format 'for x in y': for i in range(0, len(all_products_list), 3)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There's a divisibleby tag.

So you can do something (ugly) like:

```
<table><tr>
{% for field in form %}
   <td>{{ field }}</td>
   {% if forloop.last %}
     </tr>
   {% else %}
     {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:"3" %}
       </tr><tr>
     {% endif %}
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Alternatively, you could give your form class a `table_print` method that returns a html string (wrapped in `mark_safe`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it is a template tag, which is ofcourse a list of data retrieved from mysql

Answer (score -2):

```
<table>
{% for i in range(0, len(stuff), 3) %}
    <tr>
    {% for j in range(3) %}
        <td>{{ stuff[i+j] }}</td>
    {% endfor %}     
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Sorry misunderstood question.

Comment: Thanks for such a fast answer but syntax error? This method didn't work in template?